# Sed remove all beginning pattern matches from line

Tags: sed

I have the following line:

```
abababtestab
```

I'm trying to figure out a `sed` expression to remove all occurrences of `ab` from the beginning of the line so the transformed line should be:

```
testab
```

I feel like this should be simple, but I really don't know anything about `sed`.

What I have so far is:

```
sed 's/^ab//'
```

But this only removes the first occurrence of ab.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```sh
sed 's/^\(ab\)*//' <in >out
```

You should group it.

```sh
echo ababababtestab |
sed 's/^\(ab\)*//'
```

---

```
testab
```

Some [older `sed`s](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq7.html) may not handle that very well, though. Though sub-expression duplication is a [POSIX-specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap09.html) feature of BRE, some `sed`s don't properly support it. In some of those, though...

```sh
echo abababtestab |
sed 's/^\(ab\)\1*//'
```

...might work instead.

Comment: Even 7th Edition `sed` from circa 1979 supported it.  It would have to be an inferior imitation not to handle the grouping.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - see the POSIX [*Regular Expression Rationale*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap09.html), which is, partly, what I based the statement on. Maybe it's an assumption, but there's a paragraph there... *The standard developers regarded the common historical behavior, which supported `\n*`, but not `\n\{min,max\}`. `\(...\)*`, or `\(...\)\{min,max\}`, as a non-intentional result of a specific implementation, and they supported both duplication and interval expressions following subexpressions and back-references.*

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It also doesn't work with sed version from heirloom toolchests.

Comment: @cuonglm - the `\(ab\)\1*` version works w/ the default heirloom `sed`, and the `\(ab\)*` version works w/ the SuSv4 heirloom `sed`. At least, it does for my build. Admittedly, I built my heirloom set against musl lib C, and so I can imagine that might cause it to behave differently. But usually when a specified feature works in an heirloom SuSv4 heirloom tool but not in the default tool, it is because the dev made it do.

Comment: @mikeserv: I built my heirloom sed with glibc, and the default `/usr/5bin/sed` doesn't work with `\(ab\)*`. Do you have any comments with my answer?

Comment: @cuonglm - that doesn't work for mine either. I need to add the backref like `echo ababababtestab | /usr/heirloom/bin/sed 's/^\(ab\)\1*//'` to get `testab`. But `echo abababtestab | /usr/heirloom/bin/posix2001/sed 's/^\(ab\)*//'` gets `testab`. Comments w/ your answer? How do you mean?

Comment: @mikeserv: Yes, comment about my answer, how it compare to this? In the past, I will go with this first, but this time, I'm a little surprise that solution came in my mind first :)

Comment: @cuonglm - I was just checking that, actually. It seems to depend on the `sed` - like a lot. So I'm doing a test like: `printf %04000000s testab | tr \  \\n| paste -sdab |  sed -e:1 -e's/^ab//;t1'` and with GNU `sed` yours beats mine 2:1 - it's twice as fast pretty much every time. However, doing the same w/ the heirloom Susv4 `sed` *(I have't' tried the other yet)* and it's still going - for the past few minutes?

Comment: @cuonglm - weirder still, my heirloom set beats the fastest GNU `sed` time  close to 10:1 doing either `s/^\(ab\)\1*//` or `s/^\(ab\)*//` - whichever one works it doesn't seem to matter. But GNU `sed` can't do it - I had to give up on heirloom's `s/^ab//;t1` and I'm about to give up GNU's `s/^\(ab\)\1*//` I think it has something to do with leftmost longest - i read in some GNU changelog that it doesn't do that anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation. It's interesting and surprised to me. The slowing in matching `^ab` is weird. So stick to the POSIX standard is best in this case.

Comment: @cuonglm - they're both standard. The heirloom tools fall down on test loops over long strings of ^ababab and the GNU sed falls down on backrefs like ^\(ab\)\1*. They will both handle the ^\(ab\)*, but GNU does the test loop in half the time, and the heirloom set does either the backref or ^\(ab\)* about ten times faster than that. I'm pretty sure it is because GNU's matcher gets caught up on stingy matches and winds up branching endlessly, whereas the heirloom sets can find the end super fast, but short matches destroy them. That's my belief anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Another `sed`:

```
sed -e ':1' -e 's/^ab//;t1'
```

With each line of input, we set up a label `:1`, then doing `s`ubstitution `ab` at start of line. If `s`ubstitution successfully, `t`est command branch to label `1`, redo the work until no `ab` pattern appeared at the start of line, we're done.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Strictly, you don't need to test: `s/^ab//; t1` is sufficient

Comment: @glennjackman: Ah, of course. Updated it!

Comment: Why the mixture of separate `-e` command strings, and multiple commands in one string delimited by semicolons? Please stick with one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to work on the reversed string. That way you can remove all (reversed) ocuurences except the first one.

```
$ echo "abababtestab" |
rev | sed 's/ba//2g' | rev
testab
```

This will work even if your string does not start with the pattern.