# If line starts with a character remove text until another character in same line

Tags: text-processing

Some lines start with a `#`, then any number (one or more digits), then `=`. Those lines starting with hash, remove text from beginning of line up to equal sign (including it).

Example in file:

```
some text
#5=get('data');
;done;
```

Out file:

```
some text
get('data');
;done;
```

Comment: The question does not show *any* research efforts: There are hundreds of similar questions (like https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/214613/320598, where the actual characters are different). I'd vote for closing this question.

Comment: Confusing use of the term "hashtag". A hashtag is a tag (username, moniker, or keyword) that starts with a hash - the `#` symbol. And the lack of prior research is worrisome.

Comment: @MartinKealey thanks fixed.

Answer (score 9):

```
sed 's/^#[[:digit:]]\{1,\}=//' < file.in > file.out
```

With most `sed` implementations, you can use the `-E` option to get extended regexps these days where `\{1,\}` can be replaced with `+`:

```
sed -E 's/^#[[:digit:]]+=//' < file.in > file.out
```

`[[:digit:]]` matches a character that is classified as decimal digit in your locale. On GNU systems, that's always the same as `[0123456789]`. On others it could match other decimal numerals (in addition to 0123456789). Beware what `[0-9]` matches is often a bit random but always include 0123456789 and no other ASCII character. If in doubt and you want to be strict as to what is matched, use `[0123456789]`.

Or you could use `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/^#\d+=//' < file.in > file.out
```

`\d` matches on `[0123456789]` only unless you pass the `-C` option in which case it interprets the input as being UTF-8 encoded (as long as the locale uses UTF-8) and matches on characters that are classified as decimal digits by Unicode such as 0123456789٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹߀߁߂߃߄߅߆߇߈߉໐໑໒໓໔໕໖໗໘໙... (though you can get back to ASCII-only decimal digits with the `a` flag of the `s/pattern/replacement/flags` operator).

They all work on the same principle, they use the `s/regex/replacement/` applied on each line of the input. The regular expression here matches on `^` (the start of the line) followed by `#`, followed by a digit (`[[:digit:]]`, `\d`) one or more times (`\{1,\}`, `+`). And we `s`ubstitute any matching occurrence with nothing.

Comment: Assuming you don't have an ancient perl, if you use `s/^#\d+=//a`, the `\d` will only match the 10 ASCII digits (`0` .. `9`). Or you can use `s/^#9(?a:\d+)=//`. But in Perl, I always use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

Comment: Thanks @Abigail, I've added a note about the `a` flag.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{sub(/^#[[:digit:]]+=/, "")}1'
```

---

Using `pcregrep`:

```
$ pcregrep -o2 '(^#\d+=)?(.*)' file
```

`-o2` prints the second captured group `(.*)`.

All credit to @StéphaneChazelas for regex.

From [`pcregrep` manual](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/pcre/pcregrep.1.en#o%7E2):

> **-o**number, **--only-matching**=number
> Show only the part of the line that matched the capturing parentheses of the given number.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```bash
~$ raku -pe 's/^ "#" \d+ \= //;'  file.txt
```

OR:

```
~$ raku -pe 's/^ ｢#｣ \d+ \= //;'  file.txt
```

Above is an answer written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Basically I've taken the excellent Perl answer by @StéphaneChazelas and translated it into Raku.

Raku has a new regular expression engine that many people find simpler to understand/use. For example, above the individual regex "atoms" can be freely separated with whitespace (which is apparently equivalent to Perl's `/x` option). Also, the `\d` (shorthand) form ***includes*** Unicode digits, so use the `[<:ASCII> & <:N>]` (Unicode) form or the `<[0..9]>` (custom character-class) form if you just want ASCII digits only.

Sample Input:

```
some text
#5=get('data');
;done;
```

Sample Output:

```
some text
get('data');
;done;
```

A note on escaping characters:  ***all*** non-`alnum` characters in Raku regexes need to be escaped or quoted to be understood as literals (think of non-`alnum` literals such as `\.`, `\*`, `\+`, etc. and imagine the remaining non-`alnum` characters as being reserved for future metacharacter use).

*[Caveat: Here it seems that the `#` octothorpe character is required to be `"…"` or `｢…｣` quoted. Backslash escaping doesn't appear to work in my hands, possibly because Raku allows `#` commenting *within* Regexes. ].*

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org

Comment: IIRC Raku allows line continuations of the form `\ (whitespace) # (any text) (newline)`; this is probably why `\#` doesn't seem to work as expected.